# Programatically performing the same operation in multiple same-level subfolders

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script that would perform a single operation - `pdflatex` - on multiple files of the same type in same-level subfolders. Here's a simplified version of the directory structure:

```
/-|
 /a-|
  | a1.tex
  |
 /b-|
  | b1.tex
  |
 /c-|
    c1.tex
```

What I'd like to do is have the script launch from `/`, and perform `pdflatex` on all the `.tex` files without having to manually include all of those subdirs in the actual script file.

The algorithm is simple enough on paper:

- Go to directory `/`
- Find all directories matching regex given in script (may also use wildcard expression)
- Go down *n* levels, again following regex as needed
- Perform `pdflatex` on all `.tex` files in current directory

... But I'm not sure how to implement this in a Unix shell script.

Do shell scripts allow for this kind of operation at all? If so, what would an implementation look like?

Comment: Which UNIX shell (e.g., Bash, ksh, sh,...) would you prefer? Or does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is what you seem to be looking for:

```
find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec pdflatex {} \;
```

This would execute `pdflatex` on all files in the current directory.

- In order to perform the action only for files `n` levels down, replace `1` with `n+1` for both `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options above.
- In order to say that you want to filenames matching `*.tex`, say

  `find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.tex" -exec pdflatex {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I might add from what others have said is a couple of parameters, given the desire as such in the question to turn it into a contrived little program.

**pdflatesxdirs**

```
  #!/bin/bash
  pattern='*.tex'
  if [ -z $1 ]; then
    pattern="${1}.tex"
  fi

  maxdepth=' '
  if [ ! -z $2 ]; then
    maxdepth=" -maxdepth $2 "
  fi

  # borrowed from @devnull ;)
  find / -mindepth 1${maxdepth}-type f -name "$pattern" -exec pdflatex {} \;
```

Then `chmod u+x pdflatexdirs`

Now call it as

`pdflatexdirs [optional search pattern] [optional maxdepth]`

With this script:

- The default search pattern here is **.tex*
- If you want to specify maxdepth, you must also provide a search
- When you do provide a search, **.tex* is appended to whatever you pass